# JavaMail passwordauthentication before sending

Tags: java, authentication, jakarta-mail

How can I catch AuthenticationFailedExceptions?

I basically have a login screen, and I get the text from the username and the text from the password. I am using Gmail authentication.

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
properties.put("mail.smtp.host","smtp.gmail.com");
properties.put("mail.smtp.port","587");

Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, 
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                }
            }
    );
```

How can I check if the authentication was successful? I know the error arises when a statement such as `Transport.send(message)` is called. But I wanted to check if authentication was successful - not actually send a message.
Thanks!

Comment: Try this http://www.dzone.com/snippets/authenticate-smtp-server

Comment: @SunilSinghBora Thanks for the link. I already have a nice compact solution though. I am going to answer my own question shortly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Transport transport;
try {
    transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
    transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com", username, password);
    transport.close();

    //Authentication success
} catch (AuthenticationException e) {
    System.out.println("Authentication Exception");
     //Authentication failed. Handle this here.
}
```

This section of code after the original section of code in the OP, will be able to verify, assuming that username and password are defined.

If the catch statements are executed, authentication failed. If not, authentication was successful.

Comment: `NoSuchProviderException` has nothing to do with authentication whatsoever. Oddly enough there *is* a *specific* exception for that, suitably named, and mentioned in other answers. -1

Comment: @EJP So you downvote? Funny. Considering this is the correct answer, as verified by me, the OP. Just take that catch block out and it works   as expected. I am not trying to send an email, just verify the authentication. Thanks, and please, hopefully do some research next time before you downvote :)

Comment: @EJP And this is my question, and if it solved my problem, my answer is correct. Simple as that :)

Comment: Yes I downvote, for misinformation. The second catch block will catch AuthenticationException, because it extends MessagingException. It will also catch all sorts of other exceptions which have nothing to do with authentication. The first catch block won't catch any authentication exceptions at all the reason I stated. The correct solution is to catch AuthenticationException.

Answer (score 0):

whenever you are trying to send mail with wrong credentials it will throw
    javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
So, you can catch that exception in catch block to resolve your problem

see docs: [http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/mail/AuthenticationFailedException.html]

```
try
{
    Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, 
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                    }
                }
        );
}
catch(AuthenticationFailedException e)
{
    // your action
}
```

Comment: No that does not work. A session is created regardless. No Exception will be thrown. An Exception is only thrown when some sort of action is taken (like sending a message, or making a connection)

Comment: can't we catch that exception at time of sending, I mean at Transport.send()?

Comment: We can, but what if there is no exception? What if the user entered the correct password and username. It would send the message then. I do not Transport.send exists. It is only Transport.send(message).